# FragmentTabHost tabs overlap tabcontent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm using a FragmentTabHost (Support library, Android) to load my fragments into tabs. However, I see that the tabs are hosted over my tabcontent. But I want my tabcontent to be laid below the tabs. How is this possible?

I have search but couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add margin to the layouts that hold the fragments.  I believe the tabs height is 56dp.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    <!--here-->
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <!--your content-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Good solution, but one backlog, the height is not 56dp, and it changes according to the content (in my case). Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3):

Setting a margin or a padding won't work because, like you said in the comment, the size of the tabs may vary and that solution depends on the height of the TabHost being constant.

I answered this already here: [FragmentTabHost content filling remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658032/fragmenttabhost-content-filling-remaining-space/31397915#31397915)

You don't need to have the container for the fragments (the tabcontent) inside the Tabhost, when you do that you're using the same space for the content of the fragments and the tabs themselves.

Just put the Tabhost inside a vertical LinearLayout and put the FrameLayout outside, below the TabHost, just like in the following sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed when setting height of `TabWidget` (e.g. 56dp) all is ok

```
        <TabWidget
            android:background="@color/TabWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp" />
```